# Access Rails session in create-react-app side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, create-react-app

I am following a tutorial which use a custom `Rails` app with `create-react-app`. `Rails` app running on `localhost:3000` and `create-react-app` running on `localhost:3001`. Everything works as expected but I have one question, is there anyway to access `Rails` session in `create-react-app` side? Currently when I want to develop I have to `build` my app then go to `Rails` side to check the result. If I want to build my app for every change the process is too slow. The problem is `session[:user_id]` is not accessible in `React` side. As I said it is a tutorial and I have never have experience with two servers running on different port. I have `cors-rack` rails and I have this setting in my `Initializer` :

session_strore.rb:

```
 if Rails.env === 'production'
  Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_calendar-app', domain: :all
 else
  Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_calendar-app'
```

It looks like the cookies sets for `React` side but `session[:user_id]` is not accessible. I just want to know is there any way to access `session[:user_id] in`React` side?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to access `session[:user_id]`? All rails cookies are encrypted and you can't just take it from cookie store.
About long build time - why are you need to make full build for every change?